# iOS how to get the OS system build number (not version number)

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried a few API, and the closest I get is the

```
ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersionString
```

which gives a string like `Version 15.2 (Build 19E258)`

Note that I am not asking about `device.systemVersion`, which is `15.2`

I am wondering if there's an API that returns `19E258` without me having to parse the string (because apple may change the format of the string in the future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use sysctl to get the build:

```c
char os_version_string[16];
size_t os_version_string_len = sizeof(os_version_string) - 1;
sysctlbyname("kern.osversion", os_version_string, &os_version_string_len, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: whats the result you get?

Comment: For 14.1.1: "23B2082"